# Running a GWT project takes a lot of space

Tags: gwt

I have been observing this for a few days now, every time i run a GWT project on my web page a lot of space on my local C drive is taken, which is about 200 MB per run. A few days ago the space left on the drive was about 50 GB, now only 4 GB is left. How do i free the space on my C drive without removing the projects i made?

Answer (score 2):

GWT generates a lot of temporary files, some of them relatively big, but cleans up after itself.

That's unless you run DevMode from within Eclipse, in which case it'll kill DevMode so abruptly that it cannot do the cleaning. This is a known issue of the Google Plugin for Eclipse: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=74

You'll find various workaround in the issue originally reported against GWT: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5261
Files are all in the temporary folder anyway, which you should clean regularly anyway (for example, setup a scheduled task to do it when you start or shutdown your computer, as is done on most other OSes)